# Add openDrawer() to hamburger menu on a header in React Native -gives error undefined

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

This is my first React Native app. I want to get the header hamburger icon to open the side bar (drawer) but it only read it as undefined. So I read that it´s not possible to implement openDrawer() on a header as it is not read as a "screen". I have not been able to understand how to change my code to make it work. Help appreciated.

My code:

```
//Header
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, View, Text, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import { Ionicons } from "@expo/vector-icons";

export const Header = ({ navigation, title }) => {
  const openMenu = () => {
    navigation.openDrawer();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.header}>
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={openMenu} style={styles.icons}>
        <Ionicons name="md-menu" size={28} color="white" />
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <View style={styles.headerTitle}>
        <Text style={styles.headerText}>{title}Title for header</Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
};

//Navigation screen

import React from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import { Notifications } from "./screens/Notifications";
import { Profile } from "./screens/Profile";
import { Header } from "./screens/Header";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();
export const Navigation = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Drawer.Navigator>
          <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
          <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
        </Drawer.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: can you show your `App.js` file

Comment: Look, `<Header />` is a component so it does not have `navigation` prop. Only Screens have the `navigation` prop. Show me your `App.js` file then I can help with this. I've got the error.

Comment: Thank you @KartikeyVaish, my App: import React from 'react'

import { View, StyleSheet} from 'react-native'
import { Login } from './screens/Login'


const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <View style={styles.main}>
      <Login />
    </View>
  </>
  )
}

Comment: Here is all the code: https://snack.expo.io/@marymaria/myfirstapp, it is broken now, because I am trying to make the login page work to navigate to the Profile page without showing the drawer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, create a folder called `navigation` where your `App.js` is located
Inside `navigation` folder create a file called `AppNavigator.js`

Then paste this inside `AppNavigator.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { createDrawerNavigator } from "@react-navigation/drawer";

import { Notifications } from "./screens/Notifications";
import { Profile } from "./screens/Profile";

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function AppNavigator() {
  return (
    <Drawer.Navigator screenOptions={{ headerShown: true }}>
      <Drawer.Screen name="Profile" component={Profile} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Notifications" component={Notifications} />
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  );
}

export default AppNavigator;
```

In your `App.js` paste this code

```
import React from "react";

import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import AppNavigator from "./navigation/AppNavigator"

const App = () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <AppNavigator />
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Your `Login.js` would look like this

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import {
  TouchableOpacity,
  TextInput,
  Text,
  View,
  StyleSheet,
} from "react-native";

export const Login = ({ navigation }) => {
  const [userName, setUserName] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text style={styles.welcomeText}>Welcome to your App</Text>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          // required
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder="Email"
          placeholderTextColor="#fff"
          onChangeText={(value) => setUserName(value)}
          defaultValue={userName}
        />
      </View>
      <View style={styles.inputView}>
        <TextInput
          // required
          style={styles.inputText}
          placeholder="Password"
          placeholderTextColor="#fff"
          onChangeText={(value) => setPassword(value)}
          defaultValue={password}
        />
      </View>
      <TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={styles.forgot}>Forgot Password?</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
      <TouchableOpacity
        style={styles.loginButton}
        title="Login"
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("NavigationTest", { userName })}
      >
        <Text style={styles.loginText}>LOGIN</Text>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  welcomeText: {
    color: "#fb5b5a",
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: 50,
    textAlign: "center",
    margin: 40,
  },
  inputView: {
    width: "80%",
    backgroundColor: "#465880",
    borderRadius: 25,
    height: 50,
    marginBottom: 20,
    justifyContent: "center",
    padding: 20,
  },
  inputText: {
    height: 50,
    color: "white",
  },
  loginButton: {
    width: "80%",
    backgroundColor: "#fb5b5a",
    borderRadius: 25,
    height: 50,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
    marginTop: 40,
    marginBottom: 10,
  },
  forgot: {
    color: "grey",
  },
  loginText: {
    color: "#ffff",
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});
```

Comment: If you have any confusion then Check this [snack](https://snack.expo.io/@kartikeyvaish/myfirstapp)

Comment: Let me know if you have any confusion or any other question.

Comment: Thank you @Kartikey I will try this out now.

Comment: Just some thing I need to clarify. I see that you added in Appnavigator the headerShown: true, should I then write headerShown: false in Login by adding the <Drawer.Navigator there as well? Or can I write it some other way?

Comment: If you don't want to show header then in `AppNavigator.js` just add  `headerShown: false` in whichever screen yoou don't want header to be shown.....For Example if you don't want to show header in `Login Screen` then in `AppNavigator.js` replace this line `<Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} />` with this line `<Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={Login} options={{ headerShown: false }} />`

Comment: Thank you so much! Also I cannot see where the header and hamburger is added? I added it manually by styling, but how is it now being called :) ? sorry, real beginner here.

Comment: Actually the Hamburger you see gets added automatically as it is in-built. `@react-navigation/drawer` adds it to the page..You don't have to add it manually. All the best :)